# Bringing a Form to the front of a Tab

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2012

When I use `Me.BringToFront()` to Form4 it doesn't bring the form to the front as you can see in the picture:

[image]

And when I use `Form1.Tab.SendToBack()` to the Tab, the Tab disappear.

How can I bring Form4 to the front and prevent the Tab from disappearing?

Comment: The form is already in the front.  Clearly visible from the title bar, it shows the activated colors.  You fumbled the TabControl, visible from its tab area showing the form's background.  Trying to show very large controls at the same time just doesn't work very well, you need to rethink your UI design.

Comment: @Hans Passant Pardon me but I dont understand what you are trying to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im able to solve it. I turn the propeties of Form1 IsMdiContainer to False then use this code

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
       Dim F As Form4
       F = New Form4
       F.Show()
       F.Owner = Me
End Sub
```